# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I'm facing below exception when I try to establish a secure connection between Zuul gateway and microservice. Both Zuul and microservice are registered to secure Service Registry Server(Eureka). Able to access the REST endpoints exposed in the microservicevia Zuul gateway. But,whenever any REST endpoint call is invoked, getting SSLHandshakeException in Zuul gateway.

**NOTE**: Generated wildcard certificate and the certificate is imported into "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts" of all microservices. Using embedded Jetty server.

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:793)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.fillRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:322)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:278)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$3.succeeded(SslConnection.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
        at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(EngineInputRecord.java:156)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:642)
        ... 15 common frames omitted`

Can anyone suggest a solution how to resolve this?